# Kotlin higher order function for passing a function to a map

Tags: kotlin

I have for example in JS a higher-order function, a function passed to a map:

```
const numbers = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
const transformFunction = x => x + 2

console.log ("transformatio:: ", numbers.map(transformFunction))
```

If I want to accomplish that in Kotlin, I have:

```
val numbers = setOf(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)

fun transformFunction (x: Int): Int {
    return x + 2
}

println("transformFunction:: ${numbers.map{transformFunction}}")
```

But Im getting errors:

> error: expecting a top level declaration println("transformFunction::
> ${numbers.map{transformFunction}}")

So what is missing to pass the function to my `map` operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pay close attention in that snippet code of js, `transformFunction` has type *function*.

So to translate that snippet to Kotlin, declare a variable transformFunction with the type *function*, too. Then you are good to go

```
val numbers = setOf(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)
val transformFunction: (Int) -> Int = { it + 2 }
println("transformFunction:: ${numbers.map(transformFunction)}")
```

The above snippet is the closest translation from JS to Kotlin. But if you want to keep your code the way it is without so many changes, here you are

```
val numbers = setOf(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)

fun transformFunction (x: Int): Int {
    return x + 2
}

println("transformFunction:: ${numbers.map{transformFunction(it)}}")
// or
println("transformFunction:: ${numbers.map(::transformFunction)}")
```

Comment: thanks @So'n im getting errors with both ways "error: expecting a top level declaration"

Comment: place `println` in a specific function like `main`,.... The error you got indicates that you are invoking a function (which is `println`) at a top-level.